# How to search JSON data associative array mysql 5.5

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have stored JSON associative array data in the column of the table in MySQL 5.5. I want to search in JSON at one specific array key with key and value 
my JSON structure :

```
   {
   "Interface_1":{
      "Caption":"[00000004] Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160",
      "MACAddress":"D0:7E:35:D3:C1:52",
      "DHCPServer":"192.168.1.1",
      "IPAddress":"192.168.1.101",
      "DNSServerSearchOrder":[
         "8.8.8.8",
         "9.9.9.9"
      ],
      "DefaultIPGateway":"192.168.1.1",
      "IPSubnet":"255.255.255.0"
   },
   "Interface_2":{
      "Caption":"[00000011] VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1",
      "MACAddress":"00:50:56:C0:00:01",
      "IPAddress":[
         "192.168.29.1",
         "fe80::d9f4:2bfa:59f:b9ba"
      ],
      "IPSubnet":[
         "255.255.255.0",
         "64"
      ]
   },
   "Interface_3":{
      "Caption":"[00000013] VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8",
      "MACAddress":"00:50:56:C0:00:08",
      "IPAddress":[
         "192.168.71.1",
         "fe80::acec:db96:af3a:4680"
      ],
      "IPSubnet":[
         "255.255.255.0",
         "64"
      ]
   }
}
```

So for search by Key Value, I have this query :

```
SELECT * FROM `extable` 
WHERE network RLIKE '"MACAddress":"[[:<:]]00:50:56:C0:00:08[[:>:]]"'
```

It is working fine but my problem is that I can not select Interface_1 and search MACAddress on it.
I want to select `Interface_1` and search `MACAddress` on it.

Comment: On a general note: This database design is not optimal. If you came up with it and can influence the design, change it from storing a formless JSON blob into a properly normalized layout (split up into tables `interface`, `ip_address`, `ip_subnet` with foreign key relations).

Comment: On a more specific note: You never want to run regular expressions (or *any* string functions, for that matter) on JSON. MySQL has native JSON functions, use them. (Although not 5.5 – you might want to upgrade, that version is more than nine years old now.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the `Interface_1` object key into your regular expression, searching from that point but not past any `}` (end of object) character for the MAC address:

```
SELECT * FROM `extable` 
WHERE network RLIKE '"Interface_1":{[^}]*"MACAddress":"[[:<:]]00:50:56:C0:00:08[[:>:]]"'
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=87fa6228f61bac45697337183b968aa4)

Comment: Will break as soon as there is an object property between `"Interface_1` and `"MACAddress"`, for example when the property `"IPAddress"` is listed before `"MACAddress"`.

Comment: @Tomalak What you say about nested objects is true, but in OPs data everything inside the `Interface` objects is either a simple element or an array (including `IPAddress`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySql inbuilt json functions for parsing/searching.

```
SELECT * FROM `extable` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(network, "00:50:56:C0:00:08", '$.*.MACAddress')
```

Edit: Just realized this is only supported in >=MySQL 5.7

Comment: Since the OP asked for `Interface_1` specifically, the path should be `'$.Interface_1.MACAddress'`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using common_schema: https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/common-schema/common_schema-2.2.sql